# JQuery - unable to spawn Click event on anchor

Tags: jquery

It is bit of a weird problem.

My header HTML looks like

```
<div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
                        <!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
                        <ul class="nav pull-right">
                            <li style="float: left;"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                            <li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a id="selDb" href="selectDatabase.html">Do Something</a>
                            </li>
                            <li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a href="coming-soon.html">Refresh</a></li>
                            <li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a href="coming-soon.html">Start XYZ</a></li>
                            <li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a id="signOut" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
```

My JS code

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#head').load('header.html');
    $.ajax({
         type: 'get',
         url: 'someUrl/signout',
         cache: 'false',
         success: function(data) {
               $('A#signOut').attr('HREF', data);
         },
         error: function(error) {
               alert("Internal server error.");
         }
    });
 });

//alert($('A#signOut'));
$('A#signOut').click(function() {
    alert('Signout Clicked');
});
```

When I **uncomment** `alert($('A#signOut')); 
I am able to get the alert but the moment I remove it, I do not get alert.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body>

<div class="nav-collapse collapse ">
<!-- .nav, .navbar-search, .navbar-form, etc -->
<ul class="nav pull-right">
<li style="float: left;"><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
<li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a id="selDb" href="selectDatabase.html">Do Something</a></li>
<li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a href="coming-soon.html">Refresh</a></li>
<li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a href="coming-soon.html">Start XYZ</a></li>
<li style="float: left;padding-left: 30pt;"><a id="signOut" href="#">Sign Out</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

$(document).ready(function() {
$('#head').load('header.html');
$.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'someUrl/signout',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        $('a#signOut').attr('href', data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Internal server error.");
    }
});

});

$('a#signOut').click(function() {
alert('Signout Clicked');
});

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks. This worked for me.$('#head').load('header.html', function() {
  $('A#signOut').click(function() {
   alert('Signout Clicked');
 });
 });

Comment: No Problem. also take a look at this -> a#signOut .attr('href', data); <- lowercase please ;-)

Answer (score 1):

```
$('a#signOut').click(function() { alert('Signout Clicked'); });
```

should be inside the `.ready()` callback

Answer (score 0):

It may be the issue with the async nature of load. How about performing the ajax call in the complete callback for load? So that it is guaranteed that the anchor a#signout exists since you are doing the ajax after load is complete.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#head').load('header.html', function(){

   $.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'someUrl/signout',
    cache: 'false',
    success: function(data) {
        $('A#signOut').attr('HREF', data);
    },
    error: function(error) {
        alert("Internal server error.");
    }
});

});

});
```

Comment: I want to make an ajax call on the click of anchor tag. First Ajax call on url: 'someUrl/signout' is setting the URL on link while, I want to make another call on click of link.